# I am using ckeditor5 and trying to get the text into a var using JS but it only give me the NULL error ... Tried everything on net Still not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, ckeditor

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="textEditor.css">
    <title>Text Editor</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="toolbar-container"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="editor" name="content">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="../ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script>
        DecoupledEditor.create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) ).then( editor => {
                const toolbarContainer = document.querySelector( '#toolbar-container' );
                toolbarContainer.appendChild( editor.ui.view.toolbar.element );
            } )
            .catch( error => {
                console.error( error );
            } );
    </script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

After watching few videos I thought Classic Editor would be easy to use .. but still the error is same...

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function insertData(){
  var blog = document.querySelector("content");
  console.log(blog.textContent);
}
```

I also tried doing this using getElementById...
But still not working...

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmjpX.png)

Comment: `querySelector("content")` selects `<content>`, which is a tag that does not exist in your HTML. Surely you mean `"[name=content]"` or `"#editor"` or `getElementById("editor")`

Comment: Yes, but ```getElementById("editor")``` is also not working ... It only passes the NULL value

Comment: BTW thanks for your help ... After reading that I got my ans .. I was using Iframe soo I had to get the document inside the I frame and it is working properly now...
```
function insertData(){
  var iframe1 = document.getElementById("editorSection");
  var innerWindow = iframe1.contentDocument || iframe1.contentWindow.document;
  var blog= innerWindow.getElementById("editor");
  console.log(blog.textContent);
}
```

This works properly...
Thank you...